# How to highlight a button without holding it in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, highlight

I currently have a button in my side menu linked to my swift file so that it loads up a certain URL when clicked, and although it goes to said site when I tap the button, the title of the button won't highlight if I tap it, it only highlights to gray if I hold in the button for a second or two. How do I get it to react to my touch instantly?

[image: Here's my menu bar]

[image: Button IB]

My reputation isn't high enough to post more than two links.

Also, heres how I link it in the swift file:

```
@IBAction func openCurrentUpcomingRaffles(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://studiobash.herokuapp.com/dayofevent")
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

Comment: Please share your implementation - either code or interface builder, so we can see how you've set up this button.

Comment: Added pictures, I have 4 but can only post 2 right now.

Comment: do you want your button to `stay highlighted` after `user input` or you want your button to  respond immediately after user input for a second and no need to stay highlighted ?

Comment: I actually fixed it doing it differently, I just added regular views behind each  button and whenever the action was taken of clicking on the button, I programmatically changed the background color of the normal view to a light grey so you could tell which menu item you were currently viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I ended up just adding regular views behind each button and whenever the action was taken of clicking on the button, I programmatically changed the background color of the normal view to a light grey so you could tell which menu item you were currently viewing:

yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the button type to Custom?

Comment: Yes, changing it to custom actually makes it so it won't highlight at all even if i hold it in, so I tried messing with the "drawing" settings and the "state config" settings to no avail.